# PHP Passing global variables within functions in a class

Tags: php, function, class, global

I want the output 'hello', but don't get any results. The results page is empty. What is the bug in this code? This code is just a template. Original code is too long. It works fine when the class isn't used.

```
class a{

    public function one() {

      global $newVar;
      $newVar = "hello";
    }

    public function two() {
        one();    
        global $newVar;
        echo $newVar;
    }
}

$ab = new a;
$ab->two();
```

Comment: Since it's a class method you have to ues `$this` e.g. `$this->one();`

Comment: check your error log or enable error displaying.

Comment: Why are you even using globals in a class anyway? You probably want class members for this.

Comment: You shouldn't use `global` statement... there's always another way...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably receiving this error somewhere:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function one()

This is because there is no global function `one` that is being called from `two`.  There is, though, a class method `one` that can be called:

```
public function two() {
    $this->one();    
    global $newVar;
    echo $newVar;
}
```